# AttributeError: '_GzipStreamFile' object has no attribute '_checkReadable

Tags: python, io, gzip, rocksdb

I am trying to setup commonsearch and i am the point where backend imports alexa1m data to rocksdb, but it die with error( error below ).

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "urlserver/import.py", line 21, in <module>
        ds.import_dump()
      File "./urlserver/datasources/__init__.py", line 62, in import_dump
        for i, row in self.iter_dump():
      File "./urlserver/datasources/__init__.py", line 102, in iter_dump
        f = self.open_dump()
      File "./urlserver/datasources/__init__.py", line 144, in open_dump
        return GzipStreamFile(f)
      File "/cosr/back/venv/src/gzipstream/gzipstream/gzipstreamfile.py", line 62, in __init__
        super(GzipStreamFile, self).__init__(self._gzipstream)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/io.py", line 921, in __init__
        raw._checkReadable()
    AttributeError: '_GzipStreamFile' object has no attribute '_checkReadable'
```

have been fighting with this without progress for 2 days now.. if somebody could givme somekind of insight or advice i would be more than happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, it was problem in the data parsed to the tool, not the tool itself.

Comment: To clarify - if someone has this error, it means, the code doesnt find the file!